# How to encrypt data in Java using DES and decrypt that data into Object-c

Tags: java, objective-c, encryption

here is my java code use des

```
public class DES {

    public static String encode(String str, String key) throws Exception {
        byte[] rawKey=Base64.decode(key);
        IvParameterSpec sr=new IvParameterSpec(rawKey);
        DESKeySpec dks=new DESKeySpec(rawKey);
        SecretKeyFactory keyFactory=SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("DES");
        SecretKey secretKey=keyFactory.generateSecret(dks);

        javax.crypto.Cipher cipher=Cipher.getInstance("DES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey, sr);

        byte data[]=str.getBytes("UTF8");
        byte encryptedData[]=cipher.doFinal(data);
        return Base64.encode(encryptedData).trim();
    }

    public static String decode(String str, String key) throws Exception {
        byte[] rawKey=Base64.decode(key);
        IvParameterSpec sr=new IvParameterSpec(rawKey);
        DESKeySpec dks=new DESKeySpec(rawKey);
        SecretKeyFactory keyFactory=SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("DES");
        SecretKey secretKey=keyFactory.generateSecret(dks);
        Cipher cipher=Cipher.getInstance("DES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey, sr);
        byte encryptedData[]=Base64.decode(str);
        byte decryptedData[]=cipher.doFinal(encryptedData);
        return new String(decryptedData, "UTF8").trim();
    }
}
```

I'am a new of objective-c and have some trouble in Ojbective-c DES,
Above code is use java, I want to encrypt or decrypt a string finally get the same result in Object-c.

Comment: if Java and Objective-C are your interest, then why annoy the C++, C and IPhone tags?

Comment: because object-c is expand of c

Comment: But you are looking for an Objective-C answer. And what about the C++ tag? And apart from this: What exactly are you having problems with?

Comment: And it would be nice if you could make your post easier to read (read the help on formatting).

Comment: @Sunxc, this will help you out hopefully http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4611256/is-there-any-api-that-could-use-to-call-the-des-encrypt-and-decrypt-in-objective

Comment: @Sunxc, Look at my [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10631076/how-to-encrypt-the-nsstring-value-using-des-in-iphone). It will helps you.

Comment: @Owl: You aren't owl of gd.net, are you?

Comment: @phresnel, nullpointerexception ;)

Answer (score 0):

The CommonCrypto library (which is in C, so can be used from Objective-C, and is part of both Mac OS X and iOS) implements the DES algorithm. See, for example, this question: [Encryption for Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3234391/encryption-for-objective-c)